# Show and dynamically alter static html template color and image as per user Imput

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scenario where I want to show some **HTML templates**, User can select a template and can do just below things with that template:

1. Change background colors of those loaded static html divs
2. Select and change existing images of HTML template (I dont want to add new images on the page, I just want to modify the existing images of that template)

> NOTE: All html files are independent static pages which can be used by a user later on. (eg: lets say as a mail template)

Can anyone guide me to its implementation process? I am using angularJS here.

I tried to google but I think I am not getting the exact results, may be I am not choosing exact keywords to for. Thanks !

Comment: You can you angular routing and whenever a person changes the select and based on what they select use a different `route` that has a different `template`.

Comment: You can't really do this with angular alone. The HTML templates will need to be tagged with your angular directives/components. And you will need a backend service to save the HTML template back onto the server.

Comment: @Hoyen: Yeah, that I know. My main concern is: how to achieve this in frontend. Can u help me with any links ?